# Вывести часто встречающийся возраст

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть многомерный список (массив)

```
[['Вася','16','м','10А','5'],
['Женя','17','м','11Б','5'],
['Женя','17','ж','9Б','5'],
['Вася','16','м','10В','5'],
['Катя','14','м','8Б','5'],
['Лена','15','ж','9А','5']]
```

Как вывести все часто встречающиеся возраста?

```
17 16
```

Comment: а если в массиве 3 строки с уникальными значениями возраста - что вы хотите получить в результате в этом случае?

Comment: Хороший вопрос, пока такого не попадалось, но может сообщение предусмотреть?

Comment: вам стоит определится с тем, что вы хотите получить в результате - все элементы, которые встречаются чаще всего или только один из самых популярных

Comment: __Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос.__ Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и __укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности__ при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: воспользуйтесь кнопкой "править" под вопросом, чтобы отредактировать вопрос

Answer (score 1):

```
arr=[['Вася','16','м','10А','5'],
['Женя','17','м','11Б','5'],
['Женя','17','ж','9Б','5'],
['Вася','16','м','10В','5'],
['Катя','14','м','8Б','5'],
['Лена','15','ж','9А','5']]

arr = [int(el[1]) for el in arr]
max_count = max(map(arr.count, set(arr)))
res = [el for el in set(arr) if arr.count(el)==max_count]
print(res)
```